# Science fiction show that was shown in middle school in the 90's

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, science

I remember being in 6th grade in Home Economics (or something) and the teacher had us watching this science fiction show similar to Doctor Who where this team of people who where (orange?) jumpsuits go back in time and solve issues. At least that is what I can remember of that show. It was pretty corny.

Comment: What year were you in 6th grade? Did the show look modern at the time, or older? Was there anything else about it that was similar to Doctor Who besides time traveling and solving issues? (for example, was it British?)

Comment: The only pre-90's color TV show I can think of that involved time travel, jumpsuits, and fixing things was Quantum Leap... but that wasn't a "team" of people, it was just Sam and his hologram buddy Al. There was also the TimeCop series in 1997, but they wore dark blue and/or black jumpsuits.

Comment: *Misfits* (British sci-fi show that aired a few years ago) had juveniles with powers in orange jumpsuits, but they only traveled back in time in a few episodes.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I thought of Misfits, but it didn't come on TV until 2009. This is something from the 90's (or older) apparently.

Comment: @Omegacron
Ah, you're right. Huh. I was in middle school back then, but this is not ringing any bells.

Comment: In which country did it air?

Comment: Definitely wasn't Misfits. I was in the 6th grade in 1994. I want to say it was something like The Tomorrow People (1973) and Timeslip. It was obviously low budget and the acting wasn't too great. I'm wondering if it was some kind of special series used just in schools, kind of like Mr. Goodbody but for teaching problem solving skills and/or science. I'll try to remember more details if I can.

Comment: [Seven Days](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0167720/) had a chrononaut with an orange jumpsuit whose task was to go back in time to fix things (alone, though he worked with a team). *Corny* is a rather careful description. The series didn't start until 1998, though.

Comment: Could you not just ask your Home-Ec teacher what it was called?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216814/90s-2000s-tv-show-man-uses-government-time-machine-to-fix-national-problems (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

This might be [Seven Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Days_%28TV_series%29), which aired from 1998-2001. In this TV show they had a technology to travel 7 days back in time and used it to solve problems, and the time traveller wore an orange suit.

Answer (score 1):

I also remember this show when I was in 6th. I don't know if they went back in time or into the future but it seemed like after some sort of apocalypse. They all wore orange jumpsuits and they were in the library figuring out the Dewey Decimal System, and also figuring out what words meant. There were other people outside but they didn't speak; they were dirty and they seemed really stupid. I've been trying to find the show myself on the Internet. I watched in language arts I believe. Somewhere between 1991 and 1993 is when I saw it.

Comment: A "schools program" of some description?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/72111)

Comment: @phantom42 - [Partial answers need love too](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), and deserve upvotes.

Comment: @Richard This isn't even a partial answer, it should be a comment on the original question.

Comment: @ChrisSunami - I disagree. It shows independent research as well as adding substantially to the question. From an "identify this" perspective, it deserves recognition and upvotes for providing effort, especially from a new user.